# <TD> element invents extra space just to mess up my layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

behold my html code after apache and internet explorer have had their way with it.

[image]

Observe how my TD-element (highlighted) has the dimensions: 1056 x 196.14. Observe also that on several occassions in the code it is clearly expressed that the dimension should be 1056 x 192.

Highlighting the parent TR-element will reveal auto x 192, and highlighting the child IMG-element will reveal 1056 x 192 yet again.

So why on earth is my TD-element's height 196.14? It DOES show 4.14 pixels of whitespace between table rows when rendered. If I remove the IMG-element it does seem to work, and the TD-element becomes 192 pixels like it should be.

Chrome shows a slightly different result:

[image]

In Chrome the parent TR-element does say it is 196 pixels high, but the IMG-element is still 192 pixels. Removing the whitespace in the HTML file around the perpetrating TD-element has no effect.

Infuriating! Where are those extra pixels coming from? Any ideas? :)

Comment: Try adding style="display:block" to your image, it may be the line-height affecting it.

Comment: Have you tried using `style="width: 1056px; height: 192px;"` instead of `width="1056" height="192"`?  Contrary to popular belief, the attributes don't always size as expected.  Also, does it happen in other browsers?  IE is notorious of improper dimension rendering.

Comment: Scottux; you nailed it! Thx!
AoN; I tried it before posting! The same result. I always use internet explorer to test. Since if it passes there, it will pass anywhere ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your image to a block element to avoid the gap:

```
img { display: block; }
```